# Apply an "anti-aliasing" effect to a layer in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, anti-aliasing

I am aware this type of thing is probably very general knowledge, but after reading some tutorials I can't seem to get things right. I am a programmer, but have been tasked with some minor UI tweaks.

I have this caret as shown below, but it was much too small, so I used **free transform** and enlarged it by 200%. Now, it looks slightly blurry, and I am not sure how to rectify this.
[image]

I know anti-aliasing in fonts takes care of this type of thing, so how can I achieve the same effect with just a layer? *I can also rasterize it/convert to smart object - not sure if this helps in any way.

Comment: what's your view zoom in that screenshot? 100%? 400%?

Comment: Currently I have the zoom at 400%, though the blur is still visible at 100%

Answer (score 1):

the problem here is that you have resized a raster object by 200%. It will never look as sharp at it was at 100%, because it's not vector. The anti-aliasing is possible in fonts because they are not really raster objects.
To not have that pixelated effect your best option would be to trace the object with the pen tool and then resize the path you created, then fill it.